# Adding multiple vector files in a folder as an input in QGIS processing modeler using iterator tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, iterator, vector-layer

I have shapefiles in a folder that I intend to use as an input in QGIS Processing Modeler. I would like to iterate within the folder to add each of the shapefiles as an input. It did it in ArcGIS using the 'Iterator" tool but I prefer to do it on QGIS using similar tools like 'Iterator'.